# can i build ubuntu package without an upstream tar ball using bzr?

Tags: packaging, bazaar

I don't want to tar ball my C++ source. I think a good Makefile is sufficient to build an ubuntu package. Can't I `bzr dh-make` with out making a `tar.gz` of my source code.

My problem is that I initiated `git` on my project folder. In order to make tar ball I need to make a copy of the project with out `.git` folder and then use `bzr dh-make`. I want to use `bzr-git` plugin to right away use `bzr` on my git repository.

Answer (score 1):

`bzr dh-make` requires a source tarball per its help text:

```
$ bzr dh-make -h
Purpose: Helps you create a new package.
Usage:   bzr dh-make PACKAGE_NAME VERSION TARBALL
```

If your main issue is to avoid including the git metadata in your tarball, just create a `.bzrignore` (next to your `.bzr` folder) with the following content:

```
# Ignore git meta-data
.git
```

Comment: Can I make `git` and `bzr` mutually exclusive with `.gitignore` and `.bzrignore` with their references in one another?

Comment: Of course you can. Place both at the top-level directory of your project.